# Place "sum" and "multiply" operators between the elements of a given list of integers so that the expression results in a specified value

Tags: algorithm, math, combinations

I was given a tricky question.
Given:
**A = [a1,a2,...an]** (list of positive integers with length "n")
**r** (positive integer)

Find a list of **{ *, + }** operators
O = [o1,o2,...on-1]
so that if we placed those operators between the elements of "A", the resulting expression would evaluate to "r". Only one solution is required.

So for example if
A = [1,2,3,4]
r = 14
then
O = [*, +, *]

I've implemented a simple recursive solution with some optimisation, but of course it's exponential O(2^n) time, so for an input with length 40, it works for ages.

I wanted to ask if any of you know a sub-exponential solution for this?

**Update**
Elements of A are between 0-10000, 
r can be arbitrarily big

Comment: I certainly can't remember any algorithm that would do that, but I'm fairly certain that heuristics would be incredibly helpful if that was a real world problem. I can think of a few approaches, but as heuristics tend to do, it would only be helpful in a subset of possible inputs, and of course there would still be an infinite set of inputs that would remain O(2^n)

Comment: One simple heuristic: neither `+` and `*` (on positive integers) can produce a value less than their larger argument. So if you ever produce an intermediate result greater than `r`, you can cut off the search. Your question doesn't make it clear how the operators are expected to be grouped: if multiplication takes precedence, there's probably a better solution.

Comment: How large can `r` be?

Comment: Does a solution necessarily exist for the A and r you are given?

Comment: What are the approximate(or, better, precise) constraints on `n`, `r` and `a[i]` values?

Comment: Operation precedence is like if it was written on paper. @user2040251: I've already done the cut-off optimisations. I've also updated the range constraints to be more precise.

Comment: Is an `O(2^(n/2) * n^2)` solution fast enough?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely reasonable.

Comment: My solution ran for 2 days with parallelised brute force, O(2^(n/2) * n^2) would run for half a minute on a single thread (for 40 length input).

Comment: Is this homework, or for a competition?  I have in mind an O(rn^2)-time, O(rn)-space DP solution.

Comment: @j_random_hacker It was a competition, I managed to calculate it with a 4 threaded brute force in 2 days as mentioned before (they only asked for the result, not the code), but I'm curious if there's a sub-exponential solution or a proof of the MP hardness of the problem.

Comment: @aalmos: I've posted my description.  I've also made a (very unoptimised) implementation -- if you have the particular problem instance, could you post it?  I'd be interested to see how long it takes.

Answer (score 7):

> Let A and B be positive integers.  Then A + B ≤ A × B + 1.

This little fact can be used to construct a very efficient algorithm.

Let's define a graph.  The graph nodes correspond to operations lists, for example, [+, ×, +, +, ×].  There is an edge from graph node X to graph node Y if the Y can be obtained by changing a single + to a × in X. The graph has a source at the node corresponding to [+, +, ..., +].

Now perform a breadth-first search from the source node, constructing the graph as you go.  When expanding a node [+, ×, +, +, ×], for example, you (optionally construct then) connect to the nodes [×, ×, +, +, ×], [+, ×, ×, +, ×], and [+, ×, +, ×, ×]. Do not expand to a node if the result of evaluating it is greater than r + k(O), where k(O) is the number of +'s in the operation list O. This is because of the "+ 1" in the fact at the beginning of the answer - consider the case of a = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], r = 1.

This approach uses O(n 2<sup>n</sup>) time and O(2<sup>n</sup>) space (where both are potentially very-loose worst case bounds). This is still an exponential algorithm, however I think you will find it performs very reasonably for non-sinister inputs. (I suspect this problem is NP-complete, which is why I am happy with this "non-sinister inputs" escape clause.)

Comment: Of course, this "fact" only holds if A and B are both greater than one. Otherwise 1 + B > 1 × B.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I completely missed that. The idea should still work, I just need to slightly revise things...

Comment: So if I understand well, you start out from the "smallest possible" combination of operators, and try to reach the result while going to bigger and bigger ones? My original approach was to start out from the first element of the list, and build the list of operators from left to right recursively, collecting products and sums, and calculating sub-results on-the-fly (falling back if the sub-result is not ok). It's O(2^n) time and O(n) space, so it's still better at worst case. You say your solution will perform better in average case?

Comment: @aalmos My approach here is basically a form of [branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound). The idea is that, as soon as you start multiplying just a few integers >= 2, you end up with exponentially large values. So although there are in one sense 2^n candidate solutions to consider, you can really explore a much smaller space that looks more like nCp in size, where you can think of p being a small constant.

Comment: @TimothyShields it sounds reasonable, definitely deserves an up. I'm thinking about if there's some algebraic magic with which the problem can be broken up to smaller overlapping subproblems so that I can do some DP.

Comment: @aalmos I feel like "A + B ≤ A × B + 1" and "repeated multiplication is exponentiation" *are* the algebraic magic. This is already a form of dynamic programming, since there are many paths from [+, +, +, +] to [×, ×, ×, ×] yet each intermediate node will be expanded at most once.

Comment: @TimothyShields I've just implemented a rather unoptimised version of your method in python. It runs around 25% faster then the naive (unaware of sub-results) solution (python either), let's say for an input with length 20 and a quite big result number, it runs for ~18 seconds. My original solution (written in C++) runs for 0.4 secs for the same input (of course they are not properly comparable, I would have to write an optimised version of your method in C++).

Answer (score 2):

Here's an **O(rn^2)-time, O(rn)-space** DP approach.  If r << 2^n then this will have better worst-case behaviour than exponential-time branch-and-bound approaches, though even then the latter may still be faster on many instances.  This is [pseudo-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time), because it takes time proportional to the *value* of part of its input (r), not its size (which would be log2(r)).  Specifically it needs rn *bits* of memory, so it should give answers in a few seconds for up to around rn < 1,000,000,000 and n < 1000 (e.g. n = 100, r = 10,000,000).

The key observation is that **any formula involving all n numbers has a final term that consists of some number i of factors, where 1 <= i <= n.**  That is, any formula must be in one of the following n cases:

- (a formula on the first n-1 terms) + a[n]
- (a formula on the first n-2 terms) + a[n-1] * a[n]
- (a formula on the first n-3 terms) + a[n-2] * a[n-1] * a[n]
- ...
- a[1] * a[2] * ... * a[n]

Let's call the "prefix" of a[] consisting of the first i numbers P[i].  If we record, for each 0 <= i <= n-1, *the complete set of values <= r that can be reached by some formula* on P[i], then based on the above, we can quite easily compute the complete set of values <= r that can be reached by P[n].  Specifically, let X[i][j] be a true or false value that indicates whether the prefix P[i] can achieve the value j.  (X[][] could be stored as an array of n size-(r+1) bitmaps.)  Then what we want to do is compute X[n][r], which will be true if r can be reached by some formula on a[], and false otherwise.  (X[n][r] isn't quite the full answer *yet*, but it can be used to get the answer.)

X[1][a[1]] = true.  X[1][j] = false for all other j.  For any 2 <= i <= n and 0 <= j <= r, we can compute X[i][j] using

```
X[i][j] = X[i - 1][j - a[i]]               ||
          X[i - 2][j - a[i-1]*a[i]]        ||
          X[i - 3][j - a[i-2]*a[i-1]*a[i]] ||
          ...                              ||
          X[1][j - a[2]*a[3]*...*a[i]]     ||
          (a[1]*a[2]*...*a[i] == j)
```

Note that the last line is an *equality test* that compares the product of all i numbers in P[i] to j, and returns true or false.  There are i <= n "terms" (rows) in the expression for X[i][j], each of which can be computed in constant time (note in particular that the multiplications can be built up in constant time per row), so computing a single value X[i][j] can be done in O(n) time.  To find X[n][r], we need to calculate X[i][j] for every 1 <= i <= n and every 0 <= j <= r, so there is O(rn^2) overall work to do.  (Strictly speaking we may not need to compute *all* of these table entries if we use memoization instead of a bottom-up approach, but many inputs will require us to compute a large fraction of them anyway, so it's likely that the latter is faster by a small constant factor.  Also a memoization approach requires keeping an "already processed" flag for each DP cell -- which doubles the memory usage when each cell is just 1 bit!)

### Reconstructing a solution

If X[n][r] is true, then the problem has a solution (satisfying formula), and we can reconstruct one in O(n^2) time by tracing back through the DP table, starting from X[n][r], at each location looking for any term that enabled the current location to assume the value "true" -- that is, any true term.  (We could do this reconstruction step faster by storing more than a single bit per (i, j) combination -- but since r is allowed to be "arbitrarily big", and this faster reconstruction won't improve the overall time complexity, it probably makes more sense to go with the approach that uses the fewest bits per DP table entry.)  *All* satisfying solutions can be reconstructed this way, by backtracking through all true terms instead of just picking any one -- but there may be an exponential number of them.

### Speedups

There are two ways that calculation of an individual X[i][j] value can be sped up.  First, because all the terms are combined with `||`, we can stop as soon as the result becomes true, since no later term can make it false again.  Second, *if there is no zero anywhere to the left of i*, we can stop as soon as the product of the final numbers becomes larger than r, since there's no way for that product to be decreased again.

When there are no zeroes in a[], that second optimisation is likely to be very important in practice: it has the potential to make the inner loop much smaller than the full i-1 iterations.  In fact if a[] contains no zeroes, and its average value is v, then after k terms have been computed for a particular X[i][j] value the product will be around v^k -- so on average, the number of inner loop iterations (terms) needed drops from n to log_v(r) = log(r)/log(v).  That might be much smaller than n, in which case the *average* time complexity for this model drops to O(rn*log(r)/log(v)).

**[EDIT: We actually can save multiplications with the following optimisation :)]**

**8/32/64 X[i][j]s at a time:** X[i][j] is independent of X[i][k] for k != j, so if we are using bitsets to store these values, we can calculate 8, 32 or 64 of them (or maybe more, with SSE2 etc.) in parallel using simple bitwise OR operations.  That is, we can calculate the first term of X[i][j], X[i][j+1], ..., X[i][j+31] in parallel, OR them into the results, then calculate their second terms in parallel and OR them in, etc.  We still need to perform the same number of subtractions this way, but the products are all the same, so we can reduce the number of multiplications by a factor of 8/32/64 -- as well as, of course, the number of memory accesses.  OTOH, this makes the first optimisation from the previous paragraph harder to accomplish -- you have to wait until an entire block of 8/32/64 bits have become true before you can stop iterating.

**Zeroes:**  Zeroes in a[] may allow us to stop early.  Specifically, if we have just computed X[i][r] for some i < n and found it to be true, *and* there is a zero anywhere to the right of position i in a[], then we can stop: we already have a formula on the first i numbers that evaluates to r, and we can use that zero to "kill off" all numbers to the right of position i by creating one big product term that includes all of them.

**Ones:** An interesting property of any a[] entry containing the value 1 is that it can be moved to any other position in a[] without affecting whether or not there is a solution.  This is because every satisfying formula either has a `*` on at least one side of this 1, in which case it multiplies some other term and has no effect there, and would likewise have no effect anywhere else; or it has a `+` on both sides (imagine extra `+` signs before the first position and after the last), in which case it might as well be added in anywhere.

So, we can safely shunt all 1 values to the end of a[] before doing anything else.  The point of doing this is that now we don't have to evaluate these rows of X[][] at all, because they only influence the outcome in a very simple way.  Suppose there are m < n ones in a[], which we have moved to the end.  Then after computing the m+1 values X[n-m][r-m], X[n-m][r-m+1], X[n-m][r-m+2], ..., X[n-m][r], we already know what X[n][r] must be: if any of them are true, then X[n][r] must be true, otherwise (if they are all false) it must be false.  This is because the final m ones can add anywhere from 0 up to m to a formula on the first n-m values.  (But if a[] consists *entirely* of 1s, then at least 1 must be "added" -- they can't all multiply some other term.)

Comment: Big up for the long and detailed explanation and the nice DP solution, I really love it. Although unfortunately in my exact case I believe it can't be applied since the number r is really very big (so big that I had to use GMP to handle it - I understand that I didn't mention this in my question). I can send you the test cases if you like.

Comment: @aalmos: Ah, well then.  Still interested to see the instance.  One thing you can do is pick a moderate-size number m < r (say around a million), and solve the problem in which all inputs (a[] and r) have been reduced mod m: if there's any solution to the original then there must be a solution to this.  Then you can "fake" Xorig[i][j] using Xreduced[i][j mod m] and do an exhaustive reconstruction on the original problem, halting recursion whenever other bounds tell you the solution can't work.  This will beat brute force if Xreduced[][]'s "false positive" "true" values are sparse enough.

Comment: It might (or might not) be better to do k > 1 runs with different (and coprime) m values: then you can fake Xorig[i][j] using `Xreduced1[i][j mod m1] & Xreduced2[i][j mod m2] & ... & Xreducedk[i][j mod mk]`.  That seems like a more efficient way to get "false" values into Xorig[i][j], since all it takes is a single m value to have a "false" at that position -- but OTOH you have to keep all k bitmaps around during the reconstruction, so each m value would have to be around 1/k the size.

Comment: Last idea (for now :-P): First build X[][] up to some maximum value m (say a million) as before.  Then start up a "normal" brute force exponential-time search, building up formulae *backwards from the end* of a[].  Suppose the formula that you currently have uses the last k numbers of a[] and has value y; then if r - y < m, you can test X[n-k][r-y] and immediately know whether it's possible to complete this formula!  IOW, you can use the DP table to "widen the target" of your brute force search.  This is probably easier and more practical than my last suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach that might be helpful. It is sometimes known as a "meet-in-the-middle" algorithm and runs in `O(n * 2^(n/2))`. The basic idea is this. Suppose `n = 40` and you know that the middle slot is a `+`. Then, you can brute force all `N := 2^20` possibilities for each side. Let `A` be a length `N` array storing the possible values of the left side, and similarly let `B` be a length `N` array storing the values for the right side.

Then, after sorting `A` and `B`, it is not hard to efficiently check for whether any two of them sum to `r` (e.g. for each value in `A`, do a binary search on `B`, or you can even do it in linear time if both arrays are sorted). This part takes `O(N * log N) = O(n * 2^(n/2))` time.

Now, this was all assuming the middle slot is a `+`. If not, then it has to be a `*`, and you can combine the middle two elements into one (their product), reducing the problem to `n = 39`. Then you try the same thing, and so on. If you analyze it carefully, you should get `O(n * 2^(n/2))` as the asymptotic complexity, since actually the largest term dominates.

You need to do some bookkeeping to actually recover the `+`'s and `*`'s, which I have left out to simplify the explanation.

Comment: I like the idea of combining the middle two numbers like that.  One idea: though it doesn't change the overall complexity, you can generate the list of 2^(n/2) possibilities for each side in O(2^(n/2)) time instead of O(n2^(n/2)) time by going through the possibilities in Gray code order.